# SELECT * FROM MULTIPLE+DYNAMIC table_name

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

A Case in point is getting data from tables which is generated every day with new name like below:

```
select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like 'ifhcraw%';

ifhcraw_2016_03_31_24
ifhcraw_2016_04_01_8
ifhcraw_2016_04_02_14
ifhcraw_2016_04_03_20
ifhcraw_2016_04_05_8
ifhcraw_2016_04_06_14
```

As you can see, there is a name convention based on rule - "ifhcraw+year+month+day+hour". But the hour of generation is not known. 
Is there any way to create some SQL script which can get all data from the tables `"where table_name like 'ifhcraw%'"`

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL with a `PREPARE` statement in a stored procedure.

Comment: Creating a new table every day seems like a bad design. Why don't you just have a single table where the date is a column that you can match?

Comment: @Barmar, could you provide some little example? May be the question is not clear. I need to get data from all tables at the same time, like: select * from ifhcraw_2016_03_31_24, ifhcraw_2016_04_01_8 ....

Comment: You want a `JOIN` between all the tables with these names? Or did you mean you want a `UNION` of them?

Comment: Have you considered using the `FEDERATED` engine to create a table that contains the union of all these tables?

Comment: @Barmar, {UNION} or {JOIN} are not useful in this case, because the table names are changing every day.

Comment: If you're selecting from all the tables at once, you need to combine them in some way. Either you're joining them or you're unioning them.

Comment: What does the fact that they're changing every day have to do with how you combine them in the query?

Comment: When you list multiple tables in the `FROM` clause, that's an implicit `JOIN`, you know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the table names in a single string.

```
SELECT @queries := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE 'ifhcraw%';

PREPARE stmt FROM @queries;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

The first query finds all the matching table names, and creates a query like `SELECT * FROM <tablename>`. Then it uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to connect them all with `UNION`, so the resulting query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
...
```

Note that by default `GROUP_CONCAT` is limited to returning 1024 characters. If you have lots of these tables, you'll need to increase [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to get everything.

Comment: thanks it working )) But I don't understand the first variable. And due to this, I can't to make changes like `WHERE ID='9400'` for each table.

Comment: I did it  `...GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name, ' WHERE ID=\'9429\'') SEPARATOR ' UNION ').... ` Many many thanks.

Comment: Add a caveat about `group_concat_max_len`.

Comment: You are best ;) Thanks.